# Pin Marker image Corona SDK

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, coronasdk

Can I insert another image as a pin in Google Maps? The project is created with Corona SDK (Lua).
Thanks.

Comment: Check [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons) how to definew an icon for a mrker. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'll give you some links to start out

http://blog.mridey.com/2010/03/using-markerimage-in-maps-javascript.html

Some standard markers in a sprite image:

http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/de_ALL/mapfiles/ms2/iconm.png

I like the dynamic images

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons.html

Comment: He said he is using Corona, which is built in Lua and not JS.  Corona does not (currently) have support for custom images or touch events on map markers.